# Usage of optimize in R.

Tags: r, optimization

So I have a function w.r.t $x$, that is actually an integral that is evaluated w.r.t $t$. So I made a nested function, but once I try to optimize it i get an annoying error.

I believe it's because the integral needs the assumption $x > 5/2$ in order to be evaluatable. How does one assume parameters in R? Here is my code and the error:

```
g = function(x){
  f = function(t) {exp(-((x*t)^3))^(1/3)*(1-(1-exp(-((10*x/(2*x-5))*t)^(1/3)))^2)}
  R = integrate(f,0,Inf)
}
g=Vectorize(g)

optimize(g, c(0.1, 10), tol = 0.0001)
```

ERROR:

```
Error in optimize(g, c(0.1, 10), tol = 1e-04) : 
  invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

Doing this with Maple is much easier. Just with [integral] assuming $x >5/2$ I got the answer to be $x=5.258565455$, which is correct.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You say that `x` needs to be greater than 5/2, but your initial range is `c(0.1, 10)`, so it's likely `optimize` will try to evaluate the integral at `x = 0.1`.  Besides the suggestion in the answer below, it would be a good idea to set the initial range to `c(5/2 + 0.00001, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `integrate()` function in R gives you a list of elements. Logically, you only need the value of the integral, i.e.,

```
g <- function (x) {
    f <- function (t) exp(-((x*t)^3))^(1/3)*(1-(1-exp(-((10*x/(2*x-5))*t)^(1/3)))^2)
    integrate(f, 0, Inf)$value
}

optimize(g, c(0.1, 10), tol = 0.0001)
```

Comment: Also, I think there is no need to vectorize